# MapRoute template syntax for multiple prefix rules

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have several APIs (5 currently) being served from the same MVC Core application.

I'm trying to define a maproute like this, but I don't know the correct syntax, or if it even exist:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "apiDefault",
   template: "{" + string.Join("|", _apis) + "}/{*url}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ApiNotFound" });
```

I could add 5 identical rules, but I would prefer if I could avoid it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solution was quite simple. I defined the prefix as a custom constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "apiDefault",
   template: "{api}/{*url}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ApiNotFound" },
   constraints: new RouteValueDictionary
   {
      { "api", string.Join("|", _apis) }
   });
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace "string.Join" by Regex ?